# How to fix the Grid blowout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been working on a memory game using HTML, CSS and javascript. The game works fine, but I came across a problem in the layout. 
The Memory game has 4*4 grid layout and It has images hidden in it. When the grid is clicked , the image under the grid is revealed. But, when the images are revealed , the grid expands to fit the size of the image. I have attached the image of my game screen below.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="topic">
<center>Memory Game</center>

</div>
<br>
<main>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="1">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="2">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="3">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="4">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="5">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="6">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="7">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="8">
        <img src="images/logo.png"alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="9">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="10">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="11">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="12">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="13">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="14">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="15">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>
    <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="16">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="card back" />
    </button>

    </div>
   </main>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 }


 body {
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 background: url(resources/pexels_white_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 background-size: cover;
 }


 main {
  width:50vw;
  height:50vh;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left:25%;
  bottom:0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:10px 10px;
  } 
  button {
   background-color: white;
   border: solid black 1px;
 }

 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  object-fit: cover;
  }
```

if U see the image below, the grid in the first row are expanded to the size of the portrait images and remaining grids in the first row are also expanded because of this.

Can someone help me to fix this problem
[image: if u see the image below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to trick the elements to 1:1 aspect ratio. The only pure CSS way to do that is via relative `padding`, as it's always calculated from element's width.

Add the following style to your buttons:

```css
button {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Also, you'd need to replace your images with applying `background-image` to the buttons, because fitting an image in the button the way you need gets really quirky.

I personally like to avoid buttons in cases like yours, as buttons cause multiple styling problems.

Comment: I tried the above changes you suggested but still its the same, the grid expands for the image

Comment: I just figured out you didn't define your cells height at all. Updating my answer.

Comment: The real question is: do they need to be buttons? What does this interface do?

Comment: the buttons onclick will reveal the image present behind .

Comment: I don't like HTML buttons in most cases, they cause too much trouble. I would put raw images there to be honest. But if you want to stick to buttons, doing like I said plus using `background-image` will do its job.

Comment: can you help me with making the changes to background-image, how to do it

Comment: So instead of having an `<img>`, you would place `<button style="background-image: url('images/logo.png')">` in your HTML (so you can put any image you want per each button.) Then in your CSS you can customize your background, like: `button {background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: contain;}`.